# Inconsistent documentation for Android permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-location

I encountered inconsistencies in the Android documentation regarding location permissions. My app requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission for Bluetooth, WiFi, and SDK functionalities, and it operates without issues using only this permission.

However, I recently came across the [Request location permissions](https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions#approximate-request) documentation, which suggests that ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION should always be requested alongside ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. It mentions potential issues on some Android 12 builds where omitting ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION could lead to ungrantable permissions.

This was surprising, as neither the [Bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions), [Request permission to access nearby Wi-Fi devices](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/wifi/wifi-permissions), nor the SDK documentation indicated the necessity of ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. Has anyone else experienced this discrepancy?

I want to ensure that users cannot grant coarse location access; I specifically require only fine location. How crucial is it to include both permissions for ensuring app compatibility across various Android versions?

Comment: Look at figures 4 and 5 on the first page you linked to to see what happens if the user only grants you approximate location (COARSE) and you then do antoher location permission request (again, for both FINE and COARSE). You could also show a rationale prior to that, explaining that some functionaly in your app (e.g. Bluetooth scanning) won't work without access to precise location.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I understand. However, I want to ensure a logical and clear user flow within the app. If I present both coarse and fine location options to the user but only accept fine location or have to remove features, it creates a confusing and poorly designed user experience. Which i want to avoid.

Comment: The user always has the choise to only grant your app approximate location (on newer Android versions). So if some features in the app rely on having access to precise location, then you need to explain that to the user. Note that for the `BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permission at least, there are situations where `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` isn't needed (see https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions#declare-android12-or-higher).

Answer (score 0):

> > which suggests that ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION should always be requested alongside ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

You should first request COURSE.

And only when you obtained that permission request for FINE.

Comment: This is not true, the permissions can be requested simultaneously. Also, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION can be granted even when ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION is not granted.